# Mediapipe Hand landmark detection model architecture?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, mediapipe

I am writing a bachelor thesis at the university on the topic of computer vision. In particular, I use mediapipe solutions - Hand landmarks detection. Is there an opportunity to find out the architecture of Hand landmarks detection model? I need it for a general overview and comparison with my custom model based on SSD MobileNetV2.

I read mediapipe website, and I didn't find the information I needed, except that I need a special bundle to use, which can be downloaded, but it didn't give me much.
url: https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/hand_landmarker#models

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MediaPipe doesn't give the Neural Network of Hand landmarks to us. I cannot find it too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).